# Can a fielder use the wicketkeeper's glove if the wicketkeeper has discarded it during play?

Tags: rules, cricket

If a wicketkeeper throws one of their gloves on the ground to pick up the ball and throw it more easily, then chases after the ball and picks it up and throws it to the stumps, can another fielder put on the glove at the stumps to receive the wicketkeeper's throw?

Answer (score 5):

## No.

The Laws are extremely clear on this.

Law 27.1 on protective equipment says that

> [t]he wicket-keeper is the only fielder permitted to wear gloves and external leg guards.

Law 28.1 on protective equipment repeats this exact statement, and further says

> [i]n addition, protection for the hand or fingers may be worn only with the consent of the umpires.